# Update view and use a stored procedure for it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have created a view. I want to create a stored procedure to update the view and use info("penalty" column... link- http://rextester.com/GHQW83226)  from view and add it to another table.

View:

```
create VIEW consecutive
as
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *, 
           LAG([pointsRewarded], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev1_points,
           LAG([pointsRewarded], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev2_points,
           LAG([pointsRewarded], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev3_points
    FROM week1
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10  AND prev3_points = -10 
            THEN -200
            WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10 
            THEN -100
            WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10
            THEN -50
            ELSE 0
       END penalty       
FROM cte
```

Stored procedure to update above View and use that view's info:

```
create procedure createviewupdatepenaltypointsconsecutive
    @WeekNumber nvarchar(255)
as
begin
    update consecutive
    as
        WITH cte as (
          SELECT *, 
            LAG([pointsRewarded], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev1_points,
            LAG([pointsRewarded], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev2_points,
            LAG([pointsRewarded], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev3_points
         FROM week1
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10  AND prev3_points = -10 
            THEN -200
            WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10 
            THEN -100
            WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10
            THEN -50
            ELSE 0
       END penalty       
FROM cte


/*2nd part - use info from view and add it to another table*/

;WITH cte_1
         as (SELECT EmployeeID
                   ,SUM(penalty) as totalpenalty
              FROM consecutive /*(**error says** :Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.) */

              WHERE WeekNumber = week1
              GROUP BY EmployeeID)
        UPDATE d
        SET d.Total_points_Rewarded=d.Total_points_Rewarded+c.totalpenalty,

        FROM cte_1 c
         JOIN EmployeeTable d on c.EmployeeID=d.EmployeeID
end
```

Link : http://rextester.com/FSN8036

Can anyone help me solve the above issue to update a view and use its info in an another table.

Comment: why you are creating view in stored procedure,remove that part and try..

Comment: mybad,i but its giving the same errors. @TheGameiswar

Comment: `update consecutive  as   WITH ... select ` - there is no such syntax

Comment: @IvanStarostin not working dude

Comment: I know. Because there is no such syntax. "Update" means modifying data or altering view's source code?

Comment: @IvanStarostin there is syntax to update  a view.Here ,I have already created a view .So,I just want to update it within the stored procedure.

Comment: By "Update" do you mean modifying data (DML) or altering view's sql code (DDL)?

Comment: Add desired result to your question.

Comment: I just want to put the view inside a stored procedure and run.The output will be different as it will be run every week.So once I create a view ,the object is stored.So,from next time if i want to use the same view inside a stored procedure.I just want to simply "update" it. @IvanStarostin

Comment: The output is to write a stored procedure for the above queries.Right now,m getting errors.

Comment: Thanks for the input ,anyway.God bless

Comment: For "updating" objects there is "ALTER" DDL command. So you need to check out `ALTER VIEW` syntax. Both parts of view's code in your question are the same. Are you sure this altering makes some sense? The view can be refered all the time since you created it untill you explicitly `DROP` it.

Comment: Third comment from the top - there is no such syntax - that's why you are getting errors. This is not TSQL, this is something you've just thought up.

Comment: I have tried using "alter view".The point is I am able to alter is without error ,first.But once I try creating a stored procedure I get errors.

Comment: Remove this code from sp. @Squirrel has already shown you where does the `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.` error come from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alter View within stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398807/alter-view-within-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

not that place where you have indicated. but this FROM

```
 UPDATE d
        SET d.Total_points_Rewarded=d.Total_points_Rewarded+c.totalpenalty, -- Comma here. Remove it

        FROM cte_1 c
         JOIN EmployeeTable d on c.EmployeeID=d.EmployeeID
```

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I mean the ist part of the issue was to update the view.Just wanted to know if u hav any opinion on that