# Alter View within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

How can we alter view within a stored procedure ?

```
create procedure createviewupdatepenaltypointsconsecutive
as
begin
alter VIEW consecutive
as


WITH cte as (
    SELECT *, 
           LAG([pointsRewarded], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev1_points,
           LAG([pointsRewarded], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev2_points,
           LAG([pointsRewarded], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev3_points
    FROM week1
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10  AND prev3_points = -10 
            THEN -200
            WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10 
            THEN -100
            WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10
            THEN -50
            ELSE 0
       END penalty       
FROM cte

end
```

**M getting this error :** 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure createviewupdatepenaltypointsconsecutive, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure createviewupdatepenaltypointsconsecutive, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: What's the point of re-creating the view in this procedure? The view definition doesn't seem to be being altered in any way, the stored procedure isn't applying any logic nor taking in any parameters.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve needs that I put the view in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to run the `ALTER VIEW` statement like that in your stored procedure. So to solve your problem you must take 2 actions:

1) To correct the error that currently appears you have to begin the CTE with a semicolon like that:

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *, 
       LAG([pointsRewarded], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev1_points,
       LAG([pointsRewarded], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev2_points,
       LAG([pointsRewarded], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev3_points
FROM week1)
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10  AND prev3_points = -10 
        THEN -200
        WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10 
        THEN -100
        WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10
        THEN -50
        ELSE 0
   END penalty       
FROM cte
```

(Or even better begin terminating all your SQL Statements with semicolon as the alternative is deprecated).

2) Convert your alter view statement in a dynamic SQL string and execute it using `sp_executesql` as  the `ALTER VIEW` statement must be the first one in the batch:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createviewupdatepenaltypointsconsecutive
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @STMT AS NVARCHAR(MAX) =
   '
  ALTER VIEW consecutive
  AS


  WITH cte as (
      SELECT *, 
             LAG([pointsRewarded], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev1_points,
             LAG([pointsRewarded], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev2_points,
             LAG([pointsRewarded], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [WeekNumber]) as prev3_points
      FROM week1
  )
  SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10  AND prev3_points = -10 
              THEN -200
              WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10 
              THEN -100
              WHEN [pointsRewarded] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10
              THEN -50
              ELSE 0
         END penalty       
  FROM cte
   '
   EXEC sp_executesql @STMT;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.The second point ,plz tel me how to do ?

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully answer fully your question. BUT, you should really consider this as a bad practice as Damien_The_Unbeliever mentions in the comments above.

Comment: Thanks a lot.you a genius.that was quite helpful.

Comment: M getting an error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure consecutive, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: Please try it now.

Comment: same issue... but if I remove the colon before with,it works.But why ?

Comment: Sorry in my first edit I corrected it in the wrong part of my answer. The reason is that SQL Server cannot decide if the WITH refers to an option or the start of a CTE. So if you use CTEs in multi statement batches and you do not terminate your statements with semicolons, you must add a semicolon in the start of the CTE for SQL Server to understand that you are using a CTE. Practically that way you terminate the previous statement. In your case though the CTE has no preceding statement to terminate thus the semicolon is wrong. I hope I made it clear for you now!