# query changing automatically on weekend / one day per week (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use a VIEW onto a table A of another database for insert / update into my table B
The view has a condition to filter new rows to reduce Network traffic:

```
SELECT ... from A
WHERE  new_records = 1
```

Based on that view I have a stored procedure running every day hourly.

Once per week I would like to validate my table B with a query that uses all records from table A

I thought to Change that View into something like:

```
SELECT ... from A
-- WHERE new_records = 1
```

I was wondering to have a Job that changes my view. However I found that i can not exectue an ALTER VIEW in a stored procedure.

Is it possible to include something like

```
 IF today = Sunday then Do not use WHERE 
 ELSE
 ...WHERE
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398807/alter-view-within-stored-procedure

Comment: Changing metadata to match a condition is not as good as changing the query to detect the condition

Answer (score 4):

I would implement it as 2 views - the first selecting everything, and the second selecting from the first with the additional `new_records = 1` filter.

You can add in the logic you are asking about within a single view:

```
WHERE datename(DW,GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' OR new_record=1
```

But I really do not like the concept of coding that view to change behaviour on specific days, what happens when you want to run an ad-hoc verification? you would be stuck.

The proc is called hourly, but you mention you want to check it once per week, if it is a single view you would be running it as a check 24 times on Sunday as your hourly call picks up on the Sunday predicate.

Final note - if you adopted a change view approach you are required to give the executing account additional privileges that could otherwise be avoided.

Comment: This works very well and is good to understand. However datename(DW,GETDATE())  brings a result that is language dependent.

Comment: @Volker - it does, but I am recommending to not do that approach regardless.

Answer (score 1):

How about
`where new_records=1 or datepart(weekday,getdate())=7`
?

Comment: I do not understand how it does not. It is the exact code needed to satisfy the "Is it possible to include something like <sample code>".

Comment: this works fine, too: the comparison works as expected